# Delphi 7.0 DBGrid Ms-Word Hyperlink

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word, clipboard, delphi-7

Delphi, DBGrid, Right Click, Copy
What I want to do is create a hyper link on the clip board, that can then be pasted into Word
Hooked up to a DBGrid on click event

Comment: Not sure what your question actually is. Do you want to copy the contents of a DBGrid Field (a URL) to the Windows Clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is copy a URL stored in a DBGrid Field you could do the following;

```
    BEGIN
    IF DBGrid1.Fields[YourFieldIndex].IsNull THEN
      ShowMessage('Empty field, nothing to copy!')
    ELSE
      clipboard.astext := DBGrid1.fields[YourFieldIndex].asstring
    END;
```

Include in your Uses clipbrd;

If you don't want to include clipbrd you could do it a quick and dirty way using a standard Edit Box.

```
Begin
  Edit1.text := DBGrid1.fields[YourFieldIndex].asstring;
  Edit1.CopyToClipboard
End;
```

Put the chosen method into the OnClick event for a popup menu or where ever you need it.

Assuming the contents of the field is a valid URL you can paste it anywhere you want, word documents, excel, whatever.